# How to define extended properties for a Combo Box to insert & remove items in its store?

Tags: extjs

**Ext JS ComboBox properties**

```
    typeAhead: true
    editable: true
    forceSelection: false
    lazyRender: true
    mode: 'local'
    emptyText: 'Please Select'
    triggerAction:’all’
```

**Extended Properties**

```
    insertedItems:[]
```

*this property provide us to insert any items to the store with specific indexes. e.g: insertedItems:[{name:’Item1, value:’15’, index:3’}]. In onStoreLoad, this array of items will be inserted to the store with the specified indexes.*

```
    removedItems:[]
```

*this property provide us to remove any unwanted items from the store with using specific indexes.In onStoreLoad, this array of items will be removed from the store with using the specified indexes.*

**I tried this**

```
insertedItems: [{ Name: 'Manage This List', Value: 'edit', Index: '0', IsSeparator: '0'}]
removedItems: []
onStoreLoad: function () {
    if (this.insertedItems) {
        var insertedItems = new Array();
        insertedItems = this.insertedItems;
        for (var i = 0; i < insertedItems.length; i++) {
            if (insertedItems['Index']) {
                var index = insertedItems['Index'].getValue();
            }
            this.store.insert(index, insertedItems);
        }
    }
    if (this.removedItems) {
        var removedItems = new Array();
        removedItems = this.removedItems;
        for (var i = 0; i < removedItems.length; i++) {
            if (removedItems['Index']) {
                var index = removedItems['Index'];
            }
            this.store.removeAt(index);
        }
    }
}
```

Pls help me with insertedItems[] & removedItems[].
Thanks.

Comment: Assuming it is not working, tell us what is going wrong, if you are getting any error, or how your code behaves if it is not what you expected.

Comment: @Tim Thanks for your concern. I am not getting the value of displayField:'Index'.
I want to get this 'Index' value from the insertedItems[] & removedItems[] & then do the insertion & deletion on the specified indexes. Any suggestions are most welcomed.

Comment: you're calling `getValue()` on a simple object, it doesn't have a `getValue()` method, you would need to define each object in insertedItem as an `Ext.Record` in order for that to work. Why are inserting/removing items? It seems far too contrived for me

Comment: and also, where is 'Index' coming from? 'Index' should be replaced with `i`

Answer (score 0):

This should work more along the lines of what you want (I think, can't properly follow what you're saying)

```
insertedItems: [{ Name: 'Manage This List', Value: 'edit', Index: '0', IsSeparator: '0'}]
removedItems: []
onStoreLoad: function () {
    if (this.insertedItems) {
        var insertedItems = [];
        insertedItems = this.insertedItems;
        for (var i = 0; i < insertedItems.length; i++) {
            if (insertedItems[i]) {
                var record = insertedItems[i];
            }
            this.store.insert(this.store.length, record);
        }
    }
    if (this.removedItems) {
        var removedItems = [];
        removedItems = this.removedItems;
        for (var i = 0; i < removedItems.length; i++) {
            if (removedItems[i]) {
                var record = removedItems[i];
            }
            this.store.remove(record);
        }
    }
}
```